# Conditional Positioning in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have multiple views in a `ConstraintLayout` which may have their visibility set to `GONE` or `VISIBLE` depending on certain parts of a view model, like such:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.shouldShowLogo ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
```

This image will either show or disappear depending on state. Now I want to position another view, say, an `EditText` based on that same state, `shouldShowLogo`. If the logo is shown, I want to position the `EditText` below the logo, otherwise I want to position it below the top of the parent view (at the top of the screen, essentially). So far I've tried this:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchInput"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@android:string/search_go"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@{viewModel.shouldShowLogo ? @id/logo : null}"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@{viewModel.shouldShowLogo ? null : ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID}"/>
```

This doesn't compile, I get the following error:

> Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.EditText app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf> that accepts parameter type 'int'

Is this the proper way to achieve what I'm looking to do? I also get the feeling that I shouldn't be using `ConstraintSet`, but I'm honestly not sure.

TL;DR -- How can I sometimes constraint a view position based on another view when that other view is visible, and on the parent view when the other view is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GONE margins](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#GoneMargin). If your *EditText* is constrained top to bottom of the logo and the logo is constrained top to the top of the parent, then when the logo is `GONE`, the *EditText* will be constrained to the top of the parent. I think this is what you want.